# Word/VBA: How to set an other column count for a special page?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying something with Word and VBA, but i have a little problem:

I currently have 3 pages, all of them with 2 columns but I would like to have the first page, and only the first page, with 1 column.

Does someone knew how to solve this?

my code:

```
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWord.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename("Word-Dateien (*.doc;*.docx;),*.doc;*.docx"))
wordDoc.Activate
wordDoc.Sections(1).PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount NumColumns:=2
```

Here is where I currently stopped because I don't know how to make it right. 
With best regards, and big thanks for answering

Comment: I suppose when you say sites you mean pages in your word document? or is that sections?

Comment: your right, i mean pages :) im sorry

Comment: Is this a one time thing or do you want to integrate it in some other code e.g. to automate the creation of a regular report ?

Comment: i want to integrate it to automate a report. im exporting data from excel to word and on the first page i have a letter whats already formatted for 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a paragraph in your document or created by you code. e.g. you know that your first page ends after the 4th paragraph of your document.

```
Sub reportCreation()
Dim myRange As Range

'Place where your report is generated - include wordApp activation etc. according to your needs.

'Define the range after which you want to add your page break section - here paragraph 4
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(4).Range 
'Add the Next Page section Break
ActiveDocument.Sections.Add Range:=myRange, _ 
        Start:=wdSectionContinuous

'Now your report is separated in two sections: 1st section-> 1st page, 2nd section->rest of the report
wordDoc.Sections(2).PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount NumColumns:=2

End Sub
```

Comment: that works, but now i have the problem that it adds a blank page and then all of my pages are with 2 columns :/

Comment: I have added the `Start` argument in the `Sections.Add` method. The default value is producing a next page section break, where this should make it continuous. Let me know if this does the trick for you. I suspect you letter on the first page fill up the whole page, not allowing for the section break to coexist on the same page.

Comment: Hey, yeah that fixed the problem with the blank page, but im still trying to get why the first page is also getting formatted :(

Comment: Unhide your non-printing characters (Ctrl + *) and check where the section break is inserted in relation to your letter. Otherwise you could also add `wordDoc.Sections(1).PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount NumColumns:=1` to ensure the first section is always formatted to your needs

Comment: I looked at it, its inserted at the start of the document.

Comment: Apologies, I realised I made a slight error on the code. The break is added before the paragraph you select. e.g. if your letter is paragraph 1 you should set your range, before which the break is added as paragraph 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101275/discussion-between-ndslr-and-genie).